# Unable to invoke method by java reflection: NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection

We are working on a dynamic class loader project and trying to invoke a method in a dynamically loaded class via URLClassLoader. It works pretty well when it's run in Eclipse, so the invoking and dynamically loaded classes are bundled in to two different jars then deployed into Server because it’s part of requirement to split into two jars.

`NoSuchMethodException` exception thrown when calling  `mapClass.getDeclaredMethod("run", oneParam)` using reflection api.

We have verified Jar and it confirms methods being invoked is present in class.

Here is sample code..

```
import com.altova.io.Input; 
import com.altova.io.FileInput;

Input sourceInput = new FileInput(inputFileFullPath);

Class oneParam[] = { Input.class };
Object mapObj = mapClass.newInstance();
Method method = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod(RUN, oneParam);
li = (List) method.invoke(mapObj, sourceInput);
```

**Exception is**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:      
    com.sample.test.TrackingService.run(com.altova.io.Input)
```

Only difference I doubt is Input(in method signature)  and FileInput (in the parameter).

It works well in Eclipse, but not in server. It's tested with JDK 1.6 & 1.7, but server runs on jdk 1.7

Second option.. tried as shown below but this time it throws

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch*

Code

```
for (Method method : mapClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
method.setAccessible(true);
if (method.getName().equals("run")) {
    Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
    if (params.length == 2) {
        if (params[0].isInstance(sourceInput) && params[1].isInstance(outputStream)) {
            li = (List<ByteArrayOutputStream>) method.invoke(mapObj, sourceInput, outputStream);
            System.out.println(" Parsing is complete:");
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: @Dirk Lachowski thanks for the edit to make post clear and sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when the class loader changed as shown below.

`URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("file:/opt/jars/Tracking.jar") }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());`

Rest everything same... as I said, with-out adding the current class loader also worked when run in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to invoke non-public method. All you need is to make it [accessible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html):

```java
Method method = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod(RUN, oneParam);
method.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks vsminkov for your comment. edited post, error is while calling getDeclaredMethod().

Comment: tried as you suggested.. but this time it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch, any suggestion ?

Comment: @Ramesh is that possible that there is more than one `run` method in `mapClass`? In your edit you are trying to call `run` wtih two parameters while you demonstrate only single-arg `run(com.altova.io.Input)`

Comment: I'm testing on two scenarios in which method run contains one parameter and two parameters, however I forgot to mention there is overloading method with signature of `run(String, String)` or `run(String)`. so each class contains either set of `run` method with String and Input as param or `run(String, String)` or `run(Input,Output)`.

Comment: One more point, further tested today, it works in Server too when the class is present in CLASS_PATH, does not work if class is loaded via URLClassLoader. `URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);Class mapClass= Class.forName("com.sample.test.TrackingService", true, loader); Object mapObj = mapClass.newInstance();Class params[]={ Input.class,Output.class};
   Method m = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod("run", params);
   outputList = (List) m.invoke(mapObj, input,output);` `NoSuchMethodException:com.sample.test.MappingMapToTrackingService.run(com.altova.io.Input, com.altova.io.Output)`