# NoSuchMethodException exception when class is loaded via URLClassLoader

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, invoke

This question is slightly different from the previous error reported via [Unable to invoke method by java reflection: NoSuchMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972178/unable-to-invoke-method-by-java-reflection-nosuchmethodexception)

Signature of overloading methods follow as below in target class, my objective is to invoke `public List run(FileInput,StreamOutput)`dynamically.

```
public List run(String, String);
public List run(FileInput,StreamOutput);
```

Case 1: When dynamically loading a method using reflection api when target class(jar) is present in CLASS_PATH - **method is accessible**.

```
    Class mapClass = loader.loadClass("com.sample.test.TrackingService");       
FileInput input = new FileInput(inputFileFullPath); 
StreamOutput output =  new StreamOutput(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream());

Object mapObj = mapClass.newInstance();
Class params[]={ FileInput.class,StreamOutput.class};
Method m = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod("run", params);

outputList = (List) m.invoke(mapObj, input,output);`
```

Case 2: On top of the same code in Case 1, instead of placing jar in CLASS_PATH, but loaded via `URLClassLoader` then it throws `NoSuchMethodException`

Code block

```
URL urls[] = {new URL("file:/opt/jars/Tracking.jar")};
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class mapClass = loader.loadClass("com.sample.test.TrackingService",true,loader);       
FileInput input = new FileInput(inputFileFullPath); 
StreamOutput output =  new StreamOutput(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream());
Object mapObj = mapClass.newInstance();
Class params[]={ FileInput.class,StreamOutput.class};
Method m = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod("run", params);

outputList = (List) m.invoke(mapObj, input,output);
```

Exception is thrown at line `Method m = mapClass.getDeclaredMethod("run", params);`

Question 1: Is something missing here when loading class via URLClassLoader ? 
Question 2: Any recommendation on loading class definition into JVM via custom class. I mean, achieving same level as jar file present in CLASS_PATH ? Part of our requirement and limitation we can't place jar under CLASS_PATH or add jar path to CLASS_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when the class loader changed as shown below.

`URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("file:/opt/jars/Tracking.jar") }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());`

Rest everything same... as I said, with-out adding the current class loader also worked when run in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

All that should change between the two code(One using ClassLoader and other using URLClassLoader), is the instantiation, i.e.

This:

```
ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
Class<?> myLib = loader.loadClass("com.chetan.loader.MyLib");
```

Should be replaced by:

```
URL url[] = {new URL("file:C:\\Chetan\\mylib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")};
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url);
Class<?> myLib = loader.loadClass("com.chetan.loader.MyLib");
```

Here is what I recommend, though you might have tried these things, but in case you haven't:

1. Unpack the Jar `/opt/jars/Tracking.jar` (You can open it via Winzip or other similar utility), and then decompile the class `TrackingService` - Check if it does contain the method you are trying to call?
2. Give you code a fresh look / Simulate - I will suggest create a small class with the two method variants. Pack it in a jar. create a test loader class and try out using `URLClassLoader` - This will give you the confidence that the code you have written works. You can then look for other aspects of the problem.

In any case, let me know if above suggestions worked. In case you are not able to make the test class work as well, do share the code so that fellow members here can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for you comment, however it's confirmed method exists in jars and same been tested in local machine from eclipse. Issue is solved please see my answer below.